# Apache CXF and Magento runs in Eclipse but not on commandline

Tags: java, eclipse, soap, maven, cxf

I developed a small soap client to update product data on magento. So far everything works fine in eclipse. the tests are running smoothly and data is interchanged between the server and the client.

The project is set up with maven and now I would like to create an executable jar file to move this app to a server. I read the documentation of the different packing procedures and tried different plugins like jar, shade or assembly. Actually i realized that I have to include dependencies.

So if i try to run the app on the command line I always run into the same error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:92)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initializePorts(ServiceImpl.java:204)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:148)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:91)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:56)
at magento.MagentoService.<init>(MagentoService.java:40)
at client.SoapClient.getInstance(SoapClient.java:35)
at service.SoapService.login(SoapService.java:70)
at service.Synchronizer.startup(Synchronizer.java:27)
at scheduler.MagentoScheduler.main(MagentoScheduler.java:97)
```

thanks in advance

yours, fritz!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you needed to Google: cxf WSDLServiceFactory null pointer

I found this and other results pretty quick:

[Apache CXF client loads fine in Eclipse but standalone jar throws NullpointerException in WSDLServiceFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069138/apache-cxf-client-loads-fine-in-eclipse-but-standalone-jar-throws-nullpointerexc)