# CXF Webservice call works well in Netbeans IDE, but fails in standalone jar created by Netbeans (Swing,CXF,web start,Netbeans)

Tags: cxf, java-web-start

I am trying to create a shopping cart application in SWING, which uses SOAP webservice to get items from DB.

I have generated WebService client using WSDL URL in eclipse (CXF implementation) and exported as JAR to add it as dependency in my Swing application.

Following code snippet calls my SOAP web service in Swing application:

```
ItemWebServiceService itemWebServiceService = new ItemWebServiceService(ItemWebServiceService.WSDL_LOCATION,SERVICE_NAME);
IItemServiceSEI itemWebService = itemWebServiceService.getItemWebServicePort();
    try
    {
        ilv = new ItemListView(itemWebService.fetchItems(productID), this);
    } catch (ApplicationException_Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

above code works fine, when i run my application in Netbeans. But when i run my application from JAR file or as a web start, i am getting following error.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:85)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initializePorts(ServiceImpl.java:218)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initialize(ServiceImpl.java:161)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:129)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:99)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.boeing.petstore.web.ws.ItemWebServiceService.<init>(ItemWebServiceService.java:43)
at com.boeing.patterns.petstore.widgets.WorkView.productSeleced(WorkView.java:113)
at com.boeing.patterns.petstore.widgets.ProductListView$1.run(ProductListView.java:92)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I verified my dist folder, all libraries are available in lib folder and all these jars in the classpath declaration of META-INF.MF file.

Dist Folder contains:

```
lib Folder

JNLP file

App Jar
```

Did anyone have idea about the above problem?

Comment: What is the value of ItemWebServiceService.WSDL_LOCATION?  I would guess that it is referencing something invalid from the JAR file's perspective.  Also, this will probably help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4178783

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069138/apache-cxf-client-loads-fine-in-eclipse-but-standalone-jar-throws-nullpointerexc

Comment: Thanks patrick and Sebo for your comments.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19631555/390829 resolved this for me.

Answer (score 0):

I too face the same problem kindly refer the below link this may help you

[JAX-WS = When Apache CXF is installed it "steals" default JDK JAX-WS implementation, how to solve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364333/jax-ws-when-apache-cxf-is-installed-it-steals-default-jdk-jax-ws-implementat)