# Fuel SDK ETClient causing Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, gradle, salesforce, exacttarget

I know this is caused by a null value, however I'm fairly new to java and not sure *why* it's null. Have I not [instantiated ETClient](http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/FuelSDK-Java/) correctly? Or overlooked something else? I'm using the Salesforce Marketingcloud Java SDK in a class like so:

```
package exacttarget.api;

import com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.*;

public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
          // specifiy client ID and secret
          ETConfiguration configuration = new ETConfiguration();
          configuration.set("clientId", "abc123");
          configuration.set("clientSecret", "xyz");

          // instantiate ETClient object
          ETClient client = new ETClient(configuration); 

          ETFilter myFilter = new ETFilter();

          ETResponse response = client.retrieve(ETSubscriber.class, myFilter);
          System.out.println(response);
        }
        catch (ETSdkException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

It compiles (using Gradle), however when I run the jar I get the following error:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETClient).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initializePorts(ServiceImpl.java:218)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initialize(ServiceImpl.java:161)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:129)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:82)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:77)
    at com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.internal.PartnerAPI.<init>(PartnerAPI.java:49)
    at com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETSoapConnection.<init>(ETSoapConnection.java:88)
    at com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETSoapConnection.<init>(ETSoapConnection.java:178)
    at com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETClient.<init>(ETClient.java:158)
    at exacttarget.api.MyClass.main(MyClass.java:15)
```

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions.

Comment: Are you sure that you set all ETConfiguration properties that needs for ETClient constructor?

Comment: Yeah, it looks to be. Here's the doc: http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/FuelSDK-Java/com/exacttarget/fuelsdk/ETClient.html

Comment: Have you found the answer to your own question?

Comment: Here is solution for Maven: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9069435/4682359 . I hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

```
gralde: com.github.salesforce-marketingcloud:fuelsdk:1.6.0
        
ETResponse<ETDataExtensionRow> dataRows = null;
ETConfiguration configuration = new ETConfiguration();
configuration.set("authEndpoint","XXX");
configuration.set("clientId","ABC");
configuration.set("clientSecret","Xyz");
configuration.set("useOAuth2Authentication","true");
configuration.set("soapEndpoint","Soapendpoint");
configuration.set("endpoint","Endpoint");
ETClient client=new ETClient(configuration);

ETSoapConnection soapConnection=new ETSoapConnection(client,"soapEndPoint");

ETFilter etf=new ETFilter();
ETExpression expression=new ETExpression();
expression.setProperty("name");
expression.setOperator("=");
expression.setValue(DataExtensionName);
etf.setExpression(expression);

ETResponse<ETDataExtension> response=client.retrieve(ETDataExtension.class,etf);

dataRows=response.getObject().select();
```