# Unable to execute maven docker jar for CXF project

Tags: java, docker, maven, dockerfile, cxf

I have an existing working java solution based on Apache CXF to consume some SOAP service. Both the java executable and shaded jar works fine locally. However, when I tried to deploy the same solution in docker, the code

> > Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to
> >     create service.
> >             at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initialize(ServiceImpl.java:162)
> >             at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.(ServiceImpl.java:128)
> >             at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:82)
> >             at javax.xml.ws.Service.(Service.java:77)
> >             at com.flightview.BatchService.(BatchService.java:48)
> >             at de.lh.hixca.oag.ingestionraw.OAGIngestionMainClass.main(OAGIngestionMainClass.java:57)
> >     Caused by:
> >     org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to
> >     create service.
> >             at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.(WSDLServiceFactory.java:87)
> >             at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initializePorts(ServiceImpl.java:217)
> >             at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initialize(ServiceImpl.java:160)
> >             ... 5 more Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing
> >     'file:/usr/src/app/src/main/resources/jks/oag_wsdl.wsdl'.:
> >     java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> >     /usr/src/app/src/main/resources/jks/oag_wsdl.wsdl (No such file or
> >     directory)
> >             at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.getDocument(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2198)
> >             at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2390)
> >             at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2422)
> >             at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:266)
> >             at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.getDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:165)
> >             at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.(WSDLServiceFactory.java:85)
> >             ... 7 more Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/src/app/src/main/resources/jks/oag_wsdl.wsdl (No such file or
> >     directory)
> >             at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
> >             at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
> >             at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:138)
> >             at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:93)
> >             at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90)
> >             at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
> >             at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:623)
> >             at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:148)
> >             at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:806)
> >             at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)
> >             at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
> >             at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
> >             at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
> >             at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.getDocument(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2188)
> >             ... 12 more

My sample pom.xml looks like this

```
   <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.cxf/cxf-bundle -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-bundle-compatible</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--some other dependencies-->
   </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>my.correct.main.class</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!--shadded plugin-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <!--  transformers for CXF (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9069435/61298) -->
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/services/com.sun.tools.xjc.Plugin</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/cxf/cxf.extension</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.XmlAppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/extensions.xml</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.XmlAppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/cxf/extensions.xml</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/cxf/bus-extensions.txt</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.XmlAppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/cxf/bus-extensions.xml</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.XmlAppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/wsdl.plugin.xml</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.XmlAppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/tools.service.validator.xml</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.XmlAppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/cxf/java2wsbeans.xml</resource>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/cxf</sourceRoot>
                        <wsdlOptions>
                            <wsdlOption>
                                <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/jks/oag_wsdl.wsdl</wsdl>
                            </wsdlOption>
                        </wsdlOptions>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

The dockerfile that i am usig for docker build is :

```
#
# Build stage
#
FROM maven:3.5-jdk-8 AS build
#copying .m2 settings.xml for profile
COPY settings.xml /root/.m2/
COPY src /usr/src/app/src
COPY pom.xml /usr/src/app
ENV http_proxy "http://<username>:<password>@<host>:<port>"
ENV https_proxy "http://<username>:<password>@<host>:<port>"
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y openjfx \
    && apt-get clean
RUN mvn -f /usr/src/app/pom.xml clean package
#
# Package stage
FROM gcr.io/distroless/java
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/target/ingestion-oag-using-soap-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /usr/app/ingestion-oag-using-soap-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/usr/app/ingestion-oag-using-soap-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Is there an issue with my pom.xml for wsdl2java goal of not able to recognize the full  `oag_wsdl.wsdl` path that is stored in resources folder? If so, how may I tweak my dockerfile for the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your service classes were generated with absolute path (not from classpath):

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/src/app/src/main/resources/jks/oag_wsdl.wsdl
```

Try add wsdlLocation parameter for generating correct wsdl path:

```
<wsdlOptions>
    <wsdlOption>
        <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/jks/oag_wsdl.wsdl</wsdl>
        <wsdlLocation>classpath:jks/oag_wsdl.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
        <!-- <wsdlLocation>/jks/oag_wsdl.wsdl</wsdlLocation>  -->
    </wsdlOption>
</wsdlOptions>
```